# Blazor WASM Hosted: grant not being sent to the /consumers or /common endopint

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to use the ITokenAcquisition provider to get a token on behalf of a user in a Blazor WASM hosted application. The client is able to login to Azure AD for a user and establish a session.

The server application however keeps throwing this error when trying to call the ITokenAcquisition "GetAccessTokenForUserAsync" method:

```
ResponseBody: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000121: The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint
```

The goal is for the Server application to acquire a token that can call a Downstream API. I'm not sure if the Server app is misconfigured or if the downstream Web API is misconfigured. Anyone that can help on this?

I tried updating appsettings.json for the Server and Web API to use the /common or /consumers endpoint and neither works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.